# how to know that user accept oauth permission in youtube api v2 in android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-webview

i want to use youtube api v2 in android, following [developers.google.com/youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow)
when i open `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code` url in webview, it ask to access application. but how would i know if user accept it, because after accepting webview redirect to another page where i can get `success code=4/fsgko348949`

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial can be useful:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-oauth-youtube-api-access/

This tutorial shows how to detect if the user selects “allow access” using a listener:

```
package com.blundell.youtubesignin.oauth;

/**
 * This class checks what paramater's our redirect url has informing our listener
 * it also passes the auth code if access is granted.
 *
 * Google Documentation:
 * If the user granted access to your application,
 * Google will have appended a code parameter to the redirect_uri.
 * This value is a temporary authorization code that you can exchange for an access token.
 * example : http://localhost/oauth2callback?code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf
 *
 * If the user refused to grant access to your application,
 * Google will have included the access_denied error message in the hash fragment of the redirect_uri.
 * example : http://localhost/oauth2callback#error=access_denied
 *
 * @author paul.blundell
 *
 */
public class ParamChecker implements OnOAuthCallbackListener {

    private final OnOAuthListener onOAuth;

    public ParamChecker(OnOAuthListener onOAuth) {
        this.onOAuth = onOAuth;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOAuthCallback(String params) {
        if(params.contains("access_denied")){
            // User said no
            onOAuth.onRefused();
        } else {
            // User auth'd us
            String authCode = extractAuthCode(params);
            onOAuth.onAuthorized(authCode);
        }
    }

    private static String extractAuthCode(String params) {
        return params.substring(Constants.AUTH_CODE_PARAM.length()+1);
    }

}
```